# How do you create a build dependency with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I have a maven Java project (Project A) which depends on a second project (Project B).  Right now, Project A downloads Project B from the repository so it can build.  However, I am also working on Project B.  How can I get Maven to use the version of Project B which is on my machine and ignore the version in the repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both projects have the same version (and that's a `SNAPSHOT` version), build Project B locally (`mvn clean install`) and Project A will use that version.

Comment: At least unless a new SNAPSHOT will be deployed to the repository (after the local build).

Comment: Depending on the Project A's pom configuration, Project B's `<version/>` in Project A's pom.xml may need updating to x.y.z-SNAPSHOT

Comment: When using Eclipse with maven plugin, it will first rely on the Project A in the workspace.

Answer (score 2):

You can do `mvn install` on B so it will be installed into local repo and used from there by A. You can aggregate these two projects as modules of [multi-module project](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) so they can be build within same build reactor and see each other. You can also use IDE plugin (like m2e for Eclipse) that supports what you're saying about if you have both project in the same workspace.

The last option is probably most comfortable.